# Log4j2 prints odd logs

Tags: java, log4j

I am getting this odd log traces in my console :

```
[DEBUG] classPath scanning started at Thu Dec 16 13:19:13 CET 2021
[DEBUG] context false at Thu Dec 16 13:19:13 CET 2021
```

I wonder if this is related to log4j2 or Spring framework? I would love to know what does it mean actually because I keep getting these two lines after each logged line in my console as well as in myapp.log file.

This is my log4j2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
      <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      </Console>
      <RollingFile name="DAILY_LOG" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/myapp.log" 
                   filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/myapp.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%c] [%X{sid}:%X{uid}] %m%n "/>
        <Policies>
          <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>                               
      </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
      <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.works.AddWorkDelegate" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.myapp.business.util.myappUtil" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.myapp" level="DEBUG"/>
      <Logger name="org.springframework.security.providers" level="DEBUG"/>
      <Logger name="org.springframework.security.ldap" level="DEBUG"/>
      <Logger name="org.myapp.web.security" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.springframework.ldap" level="DEBUG"/>
      <Logger name="org.springframework.ldap" level="DEBUG"/>
      <Logger name="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.authenticator" level="DEBUG"/>
      <Logger name="org.myapp.web.security.sso.OrderSystemAuthenticationFilter" level="INFO"/>

      <Root level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="DAILY_LOG"/>
      </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Found those log entries here:
https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin/blob/trunk/common-tomcat-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/maven/common/run/ExternalRepositoriesReloadableWebappLoader.java

Are you including Tomcat Maven Plugin in your project and building your application as a WAR?

Comment: @DavidMališ yes I do :

$mvn clean antrun:run package -s settings.xml -P localhost tomcat7:run -e -DskipTests